# all having in direct object the establishment

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Such has been the patient sufferance of these Colonies; and such is now the necessity which constrains them to alter their former Systems of Government. The history of the present King of Great Britain is a history of repeated injuries and usurpations, **all having in direct object the establishment** of an absolute Tyranny over these States. To prove this, let Facts be submitted to a candid world.

Source: [The Declaration of Independence](https://www.archives.gov/founding-docs/declaration-transcript)

I don't understand the phrase "all having in direct object the establishment" - What does "all" mean? Does it mean "comprehensively"? Can you rewrite the phrase in today's English so that I can grasp what "having the establishment" means (the best guess I get now is it means "having the stubborn habit (of a dictator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the 'repeated injuries and usurpations' had the intention of establishing 'an absolute tyranny' over the States (according to the authors). In modern English we would say 'having *as their* direct object...'

Answer (score 0):

They were saying that, the repeated injuries and usurpations had ***one thing in common*** (***in direct object***) the establishment of an absolute Tyranny over these States.

One of those obsolete and forgotten parts of the English vernacular that would rarely be used today.

Kinda like the phrase that ultimately got Ted Kaczynski caught, because he included it in his “Unabomber manifesto” ***You can’t eat your cake, and have it too*** He was actually saying it correctly, it’s everyone else who says it backwards.